# How to iterate over a pandas dataframe and random number to each element of existing row

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to iterate over a pandas data frame and add 4 random numbers to the end of each element in a specific column but my function appending the same random numbers to each row. It is generating random numbers each time it iterates through the rows but it's only adding the first 4 random digits it generates and then appending the same one to all the rows.

```
def create_cpr(df, symbol):
    for idx, row in df.iterrows():
        number = str(rand.randint(1111, 9999))
        df['SNumber'] = df['DateOfBirth'].str.replace('-', '') + symbol + number
    df = df.drop(['DateOfBirth'], axis=1)
    return df
```

I would like the results to be

```
  FirstName LastName         Email      SNumber
0     Joe    Jones  jj@gmail.com  **27031968-8923**
1   Alice    Apple  aa@gmail.com  **11121887-5318**
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can generate all random numbers in [`np.random.randint`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.randint.html), convert to strings and add to column, also [`DataFrame.pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) is used for select and drop column:

```
def create_cpr(df, symbol):
    r = np.random.randint(1111, 9999, size=len(df)).astype(str)
    df['SNumber'] = df.pop('DateOfBirth').str.replace('-', '') + symbol + r
    return df
```

Comment: But why do you write size=len(df) inside randint function?

Comment: @Toni For same length of generated array like length of dataframe